# _pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '***_pb2.********'>: it's not found as ***_pb2.********

Tags: python, google-bigquery, protocol-buffers, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to run a dataflow pipeline from pubsub and store it in bigquery using apache-beam. After retrieving the messages from pubsub, I need to decrypt the message through a protobuf file. However, whenever I run my codes, I keep on getting the said error that I mentioned in the title. My setup would be

```
main.py
setup.py
Test_pb2/
    __init__.py
    Test_pb2.py
```

inside setup.py is

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
   name='Test Module',
   version='0.0.1',
   install_requires=[],
   packages=find_packages('Test_pb2')
)
```

Then in **init**.py

```
from Test_pb2 import Test_pb2
```

I have been trying to resolve this for days and still doesn't work. Thanks!

Comment: Are you following https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/ ? It would be helpful to see the full traceback, as it's hard to diagnose what's going on with the message alone.

Comment: @robertwb, yes, I used this as reference to the one I am creating. I'll recreate the codes to remove the confidential details and will give you link to access it. Appreciate your help on this one!

Comment: Let me know if there's any advance, so we cna hrelp youi out